# Build error with GCC 4.8: array used as initializer

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

Using gcc 4.8 on SUSE I got the following error:

Does anyone know what the source of this error is, and how to resolve it?

I come back with more details:

Having the following class

```
smoquery.h 

    class SmoQuery
    {
        public:
            SmoQuery(SqlLogonElem *        const   & eLogon,
                     optionsInfo_t *       const   & optionsInfoP,
                     logicalNameList_t *   const   & pRequestedDbList,
                     logicalNameList_t *   const   & pExcludeDbList,
                     SqlDatabaseElem *     const   & peDatabase,
                     dsBool_t              const     bIncludeFrontEndCapacity, 
                     dsBool_t              const     bReplacementChars);

            ~SmoQuery();

        private:
            Options mOptions;

            char optionsFilePath[PATH_MAX+1] = "";
    };


smoquery.cpp

SmoQuery::SmoQuery(SqlLogonElem *         const   & eLogon,
                   optionsInfo_t *       const   & optionsInfoP,
                   logicalNameList_t *   const   & pRequestedDbList,
                   logicalNameList_t *   const   & pExcludeDbList,
                   SqlDatabaseElem *     const   & peDatabase,
                   dsBool_t               const       bIncludeFrontEndCapacity, 
/*line 80 --->*/                   dsBool_t              const        bReplacementChars)
{
/* all code was commented */
}
```

Build log says:

Gmake build ... (includes were removed in this comment)

```
g++ -D_LINUX -D_LINUX64 -DLINUX64 -D_LINUXAMD64 -DMBCS_AIX -D_THREADS -D_CPP_ALL -DNO_CDE -D_LONG_LONG -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DWIDE_CHAR_FIX -DDSMAPILIB -DDSM_STANDALONE_PROGRAM -DUNIX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_NEED_USING_NAMESPACE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DSQL -O -I. -I.. .... -fpermissive -fpic -fstack-protector -Wall -Wno-write-strings -Wno-missing-braces -DBUILD_TSM_V816 -std=c++11 -c smoquery.cpp -o ../../sqlonlinux/optimized/obj816/linuxAMD64/smoquery.o

...

smoquery.cpp: In constructor ‘SmoQuery::SmoQuery(SqlLogonElem* const&, optionsInfo_t* const&, logicalNameList_t* const&, logicalNameList_t* const&, SqlDatabaseElem* const&, dsBool_t, dsBool_t)’:
smoquery.cpp:132:72: error: array used as initializer
                    dsBool_t              const        bReplacementChars)
                                                                        ^
In file included from smoquery.cpp:80:0:
```

Comment: What is `TRACE`? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And what is `TR_SQLAPI`?

Comment: Which line is line 132? (Your error message looks strange. Is there a copy and paste error there?)

Comment: The error message sounds like the problem is where the constructor is used, not in the declaration. Could you update the question with how you are trying to construct the `Query`?

Comment: I have just edit the post to enter more details. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is the initialization of this member

char optionsFilePath[PATH_MAX+1] = "";

gcc 4.8 (that i use) is misleading with the line of trouble (that caret ^ sign).

Can anyone file a bug?